# Ubuntu Trusty ppa package install not working

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa

We have had several ppa packages which normally worked (java8, php7, etc...) which appear to be now not working, and by not working I mean the packages are just not present when trying to install them.

Here is example from java8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

If I run sudo apt-cache policy i can see that the ppa is listed:

```
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED),c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
```

I know it says discontinued in the ppa, but I would except there to be an error on installing the ppa not just the package missing. Is there updated instructions on how to install java8 or other packages from ppa's (I also have the same issue with php7 from the ondrej ppa). My guess is this has something to do with trusty being EOL recently.

Comment: Possible off-topic question: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS reached EOL last month, it and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM are both off-topic on this site.  I would suggest you either upgrade to a supported release of Ubuntu, or use your Ubuntu 14.04 ESM support options (this is not one of them).  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [this web site](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) you'll see the reason why you can't get it the normal PPA way, and how to get it another way... and here's a partial quote...

---

The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16, 2019.

The new Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE is substantially different from prior Oracle JDK licenses. The new license permits certain uses, such as personal use and development use, at no cost -- but other uses authorized under prior Oracle JDK licenses may no longer be available. Please review the terms carefully before downloading and using this product. An FAQ is available here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html

Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java (and the old links were broken by Oracle).

For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way around this limitation).

Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.

Important -> Why Oracle Java 7 And 6 Installers No Longer Work: http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html

Update: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html

The PPA supports Ubuntu 18.10, 18.04, 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04.

More info (and Ubuntu installation instructions):
- http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Debian installation instructions:
- Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

For Oracle Java 11, see a different PPA -> https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/how-to-install-oracle-java-11-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Are you quoting from the WebUpd8 ppa page? or are you part of the team?  (You write using *I cannot..* many times.)  I don't see your name on the team but could easily have missed it, if you're just quoting I'd suggest making it clearer.

Comment: @guiverc I'm quoting from the web page that I gave the link for. I've clarified that in the answer now :-)

Comment: So I found out from this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/beqbs2/webupd8_oracle_java_jdk_8_installer_ppa/ that you cannot install java from this ppa any longer in any version of Ubuntu.